# Moving certain characters from one file to another

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

Let's say we have text file File1.txt that contains digits and alphabetic characters:

```
1 2 3 a 4 5
9 2 3 b
1 2 a l a i o l a
9 2 c
```

Do you know how to write a bash script that takes digits from File1.txt and move them to File2.txt, and also takes non-digits characters and move them to File3.txt?

Comment: why a bash script? this smells 'sed' + regex and redirection.

Comment: grep/sed/regex could also do a job

Comment: do you want to save the layout (i.e. if there's a newline, keep the newline, keep the spaces as they are in the input, ...) as well or only the data ?

Comment: Keeping the layouts, including new lines and spaces would be great

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - what did you try? what specific part(s) are you having difficulty with?

Comment: keep spaces? so first line would be `   a  ` for File3.txt ?

Comment: Keep spaces between characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tr` command seems like the easiest way to achieve this:

```
tr '[:alpha:]' ' ' < File1.txt > File2.txt
tr '[:digit:]' ' ' < File1.txt > File3.txt
```

giving

```
$ head File{1..3}.txt
==> File1.txt <==
1 2 3 a 4 5
9 2 3 b
1 2 a l a i o l a
9 2 c

==> File2.txt <==
1 2 3   4 5
9 2 3  
1 2              
9 2  

==> File3.txt <==
      a    
      b
    a l a i o l a
    c
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine. Thanks for the support